# Sed : Replace some characters from a position to a matching pattern

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I'm coming to you today because I would like to know how to replace text from a position to a pattern with sed.
I handle JSON and there are unnecessary characters that I would like to clean.
The starting number can have several digits (ex: 1 or 10 or 100).

**Got :**

```
[(7, {'scolaryear': '2019', 'codemodule'
```

**Expect :**

```
[ {'scolaryear': '2019', 'codemodule'
```

Comment: `sed 's/([0-9]\+,//' yourfile > newfile`

Comment: I suspect [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/#) will be a better fit for this question and that removing arbitrary data from a json file will invalidate that file.

Comment: Okay, I’ll go find out about jq. I’m not used to working with JSON but it’s the simplest to acquire data coming from requests, and I don’t know all the tools yet. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the OP was just missing any basic knowledge of regex and `sed`

```
sed 's/([0-9]\+,//' yourfile > newfile
```